# Unable to parse JSON data in ruby

Tags: json, ruby

Here are the stuffs am trying to extract data but not working as expected.

```
irb(main):004:0> config = YAML.load_file("/etc/test.yaml")
.
.
.
irb(main):005:0* asn = config["local_disk_stats"]
=> "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}"
irb(main):007:0> hash = Hash.new
=> {}
irb(main):008:0> hash["local_disk_stats"] = asn
=> "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}"    
irb(main):041:0> string = JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
=> "{\n  \"local_disk_stats\": \"{\\\"/usr\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"4263MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"5034MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"514MB\\\"}, \\\"/var\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"883MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"3018MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"1981MB\\\"}, \\\"/\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"1484MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"2015MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"428MB\\\"}, \\\"/home\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"96MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"1019MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"870MB\\\"}}\"\n}"
irb(main):042:0> 
irb(main):044:0> val = JSON.parse(string)
=> {"local_disk_stats"=>"{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=>
\"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}"}
irb(main):045:0> val["local_disk_stats"]
=> "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}
irb(main):047:0> val["local_disk_stats"]["/usr"]
=> "/usr"
irb(main):048:0>
```

Not sure what am missing here.

Comment: What's the value of `hash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the main issue is that in your `config["local_disk_stats"]` the string is not a valid JSON but an `Hash` instance `.to_s`

In this specific case you should first parse the string as you were doing (see `2.4.0 :006` below) and then `eval(val["local_disk_stats"])` instead of parsing it:

```
2.4.0 :001 > require 'json'
 => true 
2.4.0 :002 > asn ="{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}"
 => "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}" 
2.4.0 :003 > hash = Hash.new
 => {} 
2.4.0 :004 > hash["local_disk_stats"] = asn
 => "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}" 
2.4.0 :005 > string = JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
 => "{\n  \"local_disk_stats\": \"{\\\"/usr\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"4263MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"5034MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"514MB\\\"}, \\\"/var\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"883MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"3018MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"1981MB\\\"}, \\\"/\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"1484MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"2015MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"428MB\\\"}, \\\"/home\\\"=> {\\\"Used\\\"=> \\\"96MB\\\", \\\"Total\\\"=> \\\"1019MB\\\", \\\"Free\\\"=> \\\"870MB\\\"}}\"\n}" 
2.4.0 :006 > val = JSON.parse(string)
 => {"local_disk_stats"=>"{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}"} 
2.4.0 :007 > val["local_disk_stats"]
 => "{\"/usr\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"4263MB\", \"Total\"=> \"5034MB\", \"Free\"=> \"514MB\"}, \"/var\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"883MB\", \"Total\"=> \"3018MB\", \"Free\"=> \"1981MB\"}, \"/\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"1484MB\", \"Total\"=> \"2015MB\", \"Free\"=> \"428MB\"}, \"/home\"=> {\"Used\"=> \"96MB\", \"Total\"=> \"1019MB\", \"Free\"=> \"870MB\"}}" 
2.4.0 :008 > output = eval(val["local_disk_stats"])
 => {"/usr"=>{"Used"=>"4263MB", "Total"=>"5034MB", "Free"=>"514MB"}, "/var"=>{"Used"=>"883MB", "Total"=>"3018MB", "Free"=>"1981MB"}, "/"=>{"Used"=>"1484MB", "Total"=>"2015MB", "Free"=>"428MB"}, "/home"=>{"Used"=>"96MB", "Total"=>"1019MB", "Free"=>"870MB"}} 
2.4.0 :009 > output['/usr']
 => {"Used"=>"4263MB", "Total"=>"5034MB", "Free"=>"514MB"} 
2.4.0 :010 > output['/usr'].class
 => Hash
```

Anyway, I would suggest you to serialize the content of your `local_disk_stats` in the original YAML file to prevent this kind of issues

Comment: It worked. Thanks for pointed out eval which I missed to remember.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `val["local_disk_stats"]["usr"]` without slash `/`

Comment: It wont work, since the key name itself `/usr` only.

Comment: you are right. `val.class` returns `hash` but `val["local_disk_stats"].class` returns `string`. btw `val.keys` returns `local_disk_stats` as a hash key. can you post your `hash` object data?

Comment: Update the data in the question itself